# JQUERY - Container match biggest height

Tags: jquery, height, panel, containers, slidetoggle

I'm having some problems getting my container div to match the height of its children.

Basically what i'm trying to achieve is to get the container height to increase when the children inside are open. Inside the container are 2 panels that will slidetoggle independently when clicked. They both have different heights. I want the container to match the height of the biggest panel that is currently opened. If no panels are open, the height of the container should be "auto".

So in a nutshell, theres 2 panels, each with different heights. I want the container to match the height of the biggest panel that is available (open). If both panels are open, and the user closes the biggest one, the container should compensate to meet the height of the other panel. If the user closes both panels, the height of the container should return to "auto"

This is an example of my code:

```
<div class="container">
<a href="#panel1">Panel 1 Button</a>
<a href="#panel2">Panel 2 Button</a>

<div id="panel1" class="panel"></div>
<div id="panel2" class="panel"></div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {

// Add 'Height' to Content container if window is too small
    var content = $(".container");  
    var childHeight = $('#panel1, #panel2').height();

    if ($(content < childHeight)) {
    $(content).css("height", childHeight + "px");
    }

});
```

If i've confused you im really sorry! :)

Heres a jsFiddle of where i've currently got to...

```
http://jsfiddle.net/mSswY/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var heights = $("div.panel").map(function ()
    {
        return $(this).height();
    }).get(),

    maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights);
```

or you can achieve it by using a piece of css code as shown below

```
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

then for .panel these:

```
.panel {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
 }
```